# Получение всех document из одной collection в Firestore?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

я начинаю учить Android и пытаюсь решить эту проблему часами. Может быть, кто-то объяснит мне, как получить все документы из collection -> document из Firestore?

```
package com.aak.daywork.Activities.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.aak.daywork.Adapters.PostAdapter;
import com.aak.daywork.Models.Post;
import com.aak.daywork.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    PostAdapter postAdapter;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    DocumentReference documentReference;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;

    List<Post> postList;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        postRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.postRv);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String id = currentUser.getUid();

        documentReference = firestore.collection("Post").document(id);
         //Я пытался это
       // Я получаю только через id

        return root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                postList = new ArrayList<>();
                Post post = documentSnapshot.toObject(Post.class);
                postList.add(post);
                postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postList);
                postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Часто, очень полезно читать [официальную документацию](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), в которой всё хорошо расписано.

```
firestore.collection("Post")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо я там побывать, то что я написал взял оттуда. Этот код я уже вставлял